# Passar o mouse por cima da imagem e mudar a cor da legenda

Tags: html, jquery, css, layout-responsivo

Bom dia caros amiguinhos, queria saber como faço para passar o mouse por cima de uma imagem, e o background da legenda mudar de cor, no exemplo abaixo eu só consigo mudar a cor quando passo especificamente sobre a legenda. Tem como eu passar o mouse na imagem e em css chamar o outro elemento para mudar de cor?

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@font-face {
    font-family: Agency FB;
    src: url(../_fontes/agencyfb.ttf);
}
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
/*Corpo do site*/
.postagem {
 background-color: rgba(255,140,40,.0px;);
 margin: 0px;
 font-family: arial; 
 font-size: 1.2vw;
}
/*Divisão de conteudo do meu site*/
#interface {
 width: 90%;
 background-color: white;
 margin: 90px auto 10px auto;
 box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
 } 
/*Cabeçalho do meu site*/
.cabecalho {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(255,140,40,1);
 transition: 4s;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
} 
.logo {
 position: relative;
 float: right;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 25px 35% 0px 0px;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 font-family: 'Agency FB';
 font-size: 2vw;
}
#fcor {
 color: rgba(255,220,180,1);
}
/*Menu*/
.menu {
 float: left;
}
.mn {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.icon{
}
.mn a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}
.im {
 font-weight: 600;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-size: 1vw;
 transition: 0s;
 font-family: 'Agency FB';
 padding: 10px 10px 22px 10px;
 margin: 0px;
 display: inline-block;
}
.efc {
}
.im:hover {
 transition: 0.2s;
 background-color: rgba(244,116,0,1);
}
/*Postagens*/
.artigo {
 padding: 15px 25px 15px 25px;
}

.titulo {
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 12pt;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
 margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px; 
 padding: 0px;
}

.paragrafo {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
 font-family: arial;
 text-align: justify;
}
.li {
 font-size: 20pt;
 font-weight: 900;
}
.link {
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.link:hover {
 font-style: none;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
.icone {
 transition: 2s;
 border: solid white 6px;
 box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 height: 400px;
 width: 600px;
}
/*Folhas de estilo de tabela*/
.tabela {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
.tdn {
 border: solid black 2px;
 padding: 2px;
}
.vazio {
 border: solid black 2px;
 padding: 12px;
}
.vazio#vm {
 padding: 36px;
}
.tabt {
 background-color: white: ;
 padding: 2px;
 border: solid black 2px;
}
.subt {
 background-color: lightgray;
 padding: 2px;
 border: solid black 2px;
}
.ft {
 border: solid black 2px;
}
.asst {
 padding: 12px;
 font-weight: 900;
 text-align: center;
}
.galeria {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 5px
}
.galeria a {
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
.post {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}
.imgp {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.legenda {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  font-size: 9pt;
  
}
.legenda:hover {
 background-color: rgba(255,140,40,1);

}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="pt-br">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="icon" href="_imagens/icon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="_imagens/icon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
  <title>Processos e Manuais de Instruções</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/estilo.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/fotos.css"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y < 25) {
   $('.logo').css({'margin': '25px 35% 0px 0px'});
   $('.im').css({'padding': '10px 10px 22px 10px'});
   $('.icon').css({'display': 'inline-block'});
   $('.efc').css({'display': 'initial'});
   $('.cabecalho').css({'transition': '4s'});
  } else {
   $('.logo').css({'margin': '2px 35% 0px 0px'});
   $('.im').css({'padding': '10px 10px 10px 10px'});
   $('.icon').css({'display': 'none'});
   $('.efc').css({'display': 'none'});
   $('.cabecalho').css({'transition': '4s'});
  }
  });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body class="postagem">
   <header class="cabecalho">
    <nav class="menu">
     <h1 hidden="true">Menu Principal</h1>
     <ul class="mn"> 
            <a href="index.html"><li class="im"><img class="icon" src="https://image.ibb.co/hEiU5f/icasa.png"><br class="efc">Home</li></a><!--  
         --><a href="index.html"><li class="im"><img class="icon" src="https://image.ibb.co/f46hQf/ilivro.png"><br class="efc">Manuais e Processos</li></a><!--  
         --><a href="index.html"><li class="im"><img class="icon" src="https://image.ibb.co/it5bkf/iferramentas.png"><br class="efc">Equipamentos</li></a><!--  
         --><a href="index.html"><li class="im"><img class="icon" src="https://image.ibb.co/irX0BL/ietiqueta.png"><br class="efc">Inventário</li></a>
     </ul>
    </nav>
    <h1 class="logo">MANUAIS E PROCESSOS<span id="fcor"> INFORMÁTICA</span></h1> 
   </header>
  <div id="interface">
   <section class="galeria">
    <a href="_postagem/1009182.html">
     <figure class="post">
      <img class="imgp" src="https://image.ibb.co/kORwJ0/check.jpg">
      <figcaption class="legenda">Checklist de manutenção de computador</figcaption>
     </figure>
    </a>
    <a href="_postagem/1009181.html">
     <figure class="post">
      <img class="imgp" src="https://image.ibb.co/gbsE5f/win10.jpg">
      <figcaption class="legenda">Instalar sistema operacional (Windows 10)</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </a>
    <a href="_postagem/1009185.html">
     <figure class="post">
      <img class="imgp" src="https://image.ibb.co/iD2srL/oracle.png">
      <figcaption class="legenda">Instalar o software Oracle</figcaption>
     </figure>
    </a>
    <a href="_postagem/1009186.html">
     <figure class="post">
      <img class="imgp" src="https://image.ibb.co/iniAd0/office.png">
      <figcaption class="legenda">Instalar o pacote office</figcaption>
     </figure>
    </a>
    <a href="_postagem/1009187.html">
     <figure class="post">
      <img class="imgp" src="https://image.ibb.co/dMaZ5f/vnc.png">
      <figcaption class="legenda">Instalar UltraVNC Viewer</figcaption>
     </figure>
    </a>
    
   </section>
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Um exemplo do que eu quero, seria o site o WikiHow https://pt.wikihow.com/Página-principal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta vc fazer um regra que quando fizer o `:hover` no *pai* vc troca a cor do *filho*.

**Ex:**

```
<pai>
    <filho></filho>
</pai> 

pai:hover filho { css }
```

No seu caso, quando vc fizer o `:hover` na figura classe `.post` ele muda a cor da `.legenda` que está dentro dela.

Veja como fica

```css
    @charset "UTF-8";
@font-face {
    font-family: Agency FB;
    src: url(../_fontes/agencyfb.ttf);
}
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
/*Corpo do site*/
.postagem {
 background-color: rgba(255,140,40,.0px;);
 margin: 0px;
 font-family: arial; 
 font-size: 1.2vw;
}
/*Divisão de conteudo do meu site*/
#interface {
 width: 90%;
 background-color: white;
 margin: 90px auto 10px auto;
 box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
 } 
/*Cabeçalho do meu site*/
.cabecalho {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(255,140,40,1);
 transition: 4s;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
} 
.logo {
 position: relative;
 float: right;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 25px 35% 0px 0px;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 font-family: 'Agency FB';
 font-size: 2vw;
}
#fcor {
 color: rgba(255,220,180,1);
}
/*Menu*/
.menu {
 float: left;
}
.mn {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.icon{
}
.mn a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}
.im {
 font-weight: 600;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-size: 1vw;
 transition: 0s;
 font-family: 'Agency FB';
 padding: 10px 10px 22px 10px;
 margin: 0px;
 display: inline-block;
}
.efc {
}

/*Postagens*/
.artigo {
 padding: 15px 25px 15px 25px;
}

.titulo {
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 12pt;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
 margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px; 
 padding: 0px;
}

.paragrafo {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
 font-family: arial;
 text-align: justify;
}
.li {
 font-size: 20pt;
 font-weight: 900;
}
.link {
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.link:hover {
 font-style: none;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
.icone {
 transition: 2s;
 border: solid white 6px;
 box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 height: 400px;
 width: 600px;
}
/*Folhas de estilo de tabela*/
.tabela {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
.tdn {
 border: solid black 2px;
 padding: 2px;
}
.vazio {
 border: solid black 2px;
 padding: 12px;
}
.vazio#vm {
 padding: 36px;
}
.tabt {
 background-color: white: ;
 padding: 2px;
 border: solid black 2px;
}
.subt {
 background-color: lightgray;
 padding: 2px;
 border: solid black 2px;
}
.ft {
 border: solid black 2px;
}
.asst {
 padding: 12px;
 font-weight: 900;
 text-align: center;
}
.galeria {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 5px
}
.galeria a {
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
.post {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}
.imgp {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.legenda {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  font-size: 9pt;
  
}
.post:hover .legenda {
 transition: 0.2s;
 background-color: rgba(244,116,0,1);
}
/* não precisa amais desse css
.legenda:hover {
 background-color: rgba(255,140,40,1);
}
*/
```

```html
   <header class="cabecalho">
    <nav class="menu">
     <h1 hidden="true">Menu Principal</h1>
     <ul class="mn"> 
            <a href="index.html"><li class="im"><img class="icon" src="https://image.ibb.co/hEiU5f/icasa.png"><br class="efc">Home</li></a><!--  
         --><a href="index.html"><li class="im"><img class="icon" src="https://image.ibb.co/f46hQf/ilivro.png"><br class="efc">Manuais e Processos</li></a><!--  
         --><a href="index.html"><li class="im"><img class="icon" src="https://image.ibb.co/it5bkf/iferramentas.png"><br class="efc">Equipamentos</li></a><!--  
         --><a href="index.html"><li class="im"><img class="icon" src="https://image.ibb.co/irX0BL/ietiqueta.png"><br class="efc">Inventário</li></a>
     </ul>
    </nav>
    <h1 class="logo">MANUAIS E PROCESSOS<span id="fcor"> INFORMÁTICA</span></h1> 
   </header>
  <div id="interface">
   <section class="galeria">
    <a href="_postagem/1009182.html">
     <figure class="post">
      <img class="imgp" src="https://image.ibb.co/kORwJ0/check.jpg">
      <figcaption class="legenda">Checklist de manutenção de computador</figcaption>
     </figure>
    </a>
    <a href="_postagem/1009181.html">
     <figure class="post">
      <img class="imgp" src="https://image.ibb.co/gbsE5f/win10.jpg">
      <figcaption class="legenda">Instalar sistema operacional (Windows 10)</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </a>
    <a href="_postagem/1009185.html">
     <figure class="post">
      <img class="imgp" src="https://image.ibb.co/iD2srL/oracle.png">
      <figcaption class="legenda">Instalar o software Oracle</figcaption>
     </figure>
    </a>
    <a href="_postagem/1009186.html">
     <figure class="post">
      <img class="imgp" src="https://image.ibb.co/iniAd0/office.png">
      <figcaption class="legenda">Instalar o pacote office</figcaption>
     </figure>
    </a>
    <a href="_postagem/1009187.html">
     <figure class="post">
      <img class="imgp" src="https://image.ibb.co/dMaZ5f/vnc.png">
      <figcaption class="legenda">Instalar UltraVNC Viewer</figcaption>
     </figure>
    </a>
    
   </section>
  </div>
```

Comment: Você sempre fazendo um ótimo trabalho, tive que comentar...

Comment: Ajudando muitaa gente!!

Comment: Tranquilo @MarcosAurélio sempre tento te dar exemplos bem didáticos pq sei que vc está começando etc. Sempre que tenho um tempinho tento ajudar aqui o pessoal! Abs

Answer (score 0):

Tu tens que colocar o hover numa tag pai, mas mudar a cor do filho. No teu caso é só muda a última regra do CSS para:

```
.post:hover .legenda {
    background-color: rgba(255,140,40,1);
}
```

Fiz um [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/evandrobm/xpvt214o/886790/) pra demonstrar!

Adicionar um `transition: all 0.3s ease;` junto nesta regra torna a transição muito melhor